# How can I calculate $\widehat p$ on a Binomial distribution?

Tags: statistics

$ \widehat p = \overline x$ is an unbiased estimator? I think the most likelihood estimator to p is $ \widehat p=\frac{\overline x}{n}$, but what shall I use? A unbiased or a Most Likelihood estimator?

My teacher said to always use unbiased estimators, but she also said that the estimator of p was $ \widehat p=\frac{\overline x}{n}$ , however, I saw on internet that proportion is $ \widehat p=\overline x$ .. I'm confused.

Comment: It depends of what $\bar{x}$ means.  Is it the mean of a number of samples from a binomial distribution?  Or is it based on a single observation from the binomial distribution, giving the proportion of successes?

Comment: @Henry thanks , you're right

Comment: If $X$ is the number of Successes in $n$ trials, then $\hat p = X/n,$ the proportion of Successes, is the usual estimator. It is the Maximum Likelihood Estimator and it is unbiased. Specifically, if I get $X = 53$ Heads in $n = 100$ tosses of a coin then $\hat p = 53/100 = 0.53$ is the estimated probability of Heads.

Comment: @BruceET but, isn't this estimator to a bernoulli distribution?

Comment: If $X = V_1 + V_2 + \cdots + V_n,$ where $V_i$ are $n$ independent Bernoulli's, each with Success probability $p,$ then $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n, p).$ So you can speak of estimating Bernoulli $p$ or Binomial $p,$ which is the same.

Comment: I cant resist but to add a comment about "always use unbiased estimators". Unbiasedness $\mathbf{alone}$ is a bad criteria for an estimator. For example, suppose from a random sample of $n$ Bernoulli$(p)$ observations an estimator $\tilde{p}$ is defined to be $\tilde{p}=1$ if the first observation is a success and $\tilde{p}=0$ if the first observation is a failure. This estimator is unbiased for $p$ because $E(\tilde{p}) = p$. But this estimator makes use of just the first observation and as such has to be a bad estimator because it doesn't use the information from the rest of the sample.